# How can I create clone of tables in google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Currently I am doing some performance testing. For that reason I need to create 100k tables in a dataset with x number of rows. I have the sample table but how can I write a script to execute select statement with some concatenation happening inside loop.

A sample to create 10 copies

```
DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE n int64;
SET n = 10;
-- we will do this until we execute below query n times
WHILE i < n DO
CREATE TABLE `myproject.target_dataset.table_` + STRING(i)
AS SELECT * FROM `myproject.source_databaset.sample_table` 
SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
```

End Result : table_1, table_2 ... table_10 would be there in dataset.

How can I achieve "CREATE TABLE `myproject.target_dataset.table_` + STRING(i)" in bigquery scripting.

Tried "bq cp myproject.source_dataset.sample_table myproject.target_dataset.table_1...n" but its very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate):

```
DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 1;
SET n = 10;
-- we will do this until we execute below query n times
WHILE i < n DO
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "CREATE TABLE `myproject.target_dataset.table_" || i || "` AS SELECT * FROM `myproject.source_databaset.sample_table`";
  SET i = i + 1;
END WHILE;
```

Comment: Consider accepting the answer and upvoting it then :)

Comment: Would love to, unfortunately I need 15 reputations to accept and up vote it. I am new here ... Thanks anyways.